# Issue with for loop and if in protractor

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to do e2e testing of a browser based application that sends an action to a device and then monitors it. The webpage then gets updates from the application but does not auto refresh. The objective of my following code is to refresh the browser to get updates for action status, start a loop counter, check the status of the action, if the status is fixed - send that status to console and exit out of the loop, else increment the counter and repeat the loop until the counter expires or fixed or failed or locked status is returned. Also, send final action status to console.

The code is as follows:

```
    browser.sleep(30000);

    browser.refresh();

    for (var i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {

        console.log('i is: ', i);

        element(by.css('.deployment-card-status, result.status')).getText().then(function(text){

            var action_status = text;

            if (action_status == 'Fixed'){

                console.log('Action Passed');

                break();
            } 
            else {
                browser.sleep(30000);
                browser.refresh();
            }

            if (action_status == 'Failed' || action_status == 'Blocked'){

                console.log('Action Failed');
            }
        });
    }
```

The webpage is written in angular js and I am trying to test it using Protractor and Jasmine framework.

The issue is the following error code:

Error code: 100
Signal received: null
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[launcher] Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

I can't figure what this unexpected token is?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should not be calling `break()`, you should be using `break;` instead.

Though, the follow-up problem would be that `break` would not take any affect here since you are actually not inside a loop (well, if you read the code from top to bottom, yes, but we work in an *asynchronous* environment here and are inside a promise resolution function at this point). So, you would get `SyntaxError: Illegal break statement` error.

One way to solve it is by using the `done()` function - sort of a "return" from a jasmine test:

```
it("should test something", function (done) {
    browser.sleep(30000);

    browser.refresh();

    for (var i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        console.log('i is: ', i);
        element(by.css('.deployment-card-status, result.status')).getText().then(function(text){
            var action_status = text;
            if (action_status == 'Fixed'){
                console.log('Action Passed');
                done();
            }
            else {
                browser.sleep(30000);
                browser.refresh();
            }

            if (action_status == 'Failed' || action_status == 'Blocked'){
                console.log('Action Failed');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, I tried the solution you proposed. Now, instead of the previous error, I see the error:

   **bold  [31m    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.[0m
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at [object Object]._onTimeout (C:\Users\hk-sel1\e2e-testing\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1812:23)**

Comment: Also, the jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL was set to 30000 but increasing that to 60000 still leads to the same error.

Comment: @HiteshKapur yeah, I am afraid there is more to that and FlorentB is correct that you should avoid using a for loop. Have you tried his solution? Thanks.

Comment: @HiteshKapur note that though multiple `browser.sleep(30000)` called in a loop might require a much bigger jasmine default timeout interval :)

Comment: increasing the jasmine default timeout interval to as much as 2500000 still produces the same error. I will try out FlorentB approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a `for` loop since the code in the loop is asynchronous. You are dealing with `Promises`, so the right move here is to place the code in a function and call it again until you get the expected status:

```
(function checkActionStatus(i) {
    console.log('i is: ', i);

    $('.deployment-card-status, result.status').getText().then((action_status) => {

        // break if the status is Fixed or Failed or Blocked
        if (/^(Fixed|Failed|Blocked)$/.test(action_status)) {
            console.log('Action ', action_status);
            return;
        }

        // wait, refresh and retry if the counter is not expired
        if (++i < 50) {
            browser.sleep(1000);
            browser.refresh();
            checkActionStatus(i);
        }
    });

})(0);
```